# Comparing two list

Tags: c#

I have two string list -

```
 List<string> ObjList1;
 List<string> ObjList2;
```

How can I compare these two list efficiently, such a way that these should have exact match of parameter regardless of their order in the list? (count as well as exact match of string regardless of order)

Comment: sort the lists and then comparing one by one

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346458.aspx